# how to listen keydown event on ios system?

Tags: javascript, ios, keyboard

Is there any solution to listen keydown event of two blue arrow on left top corner of keyboard in ios system in HTML input tag?

[image]

BTW:I tried to bind keydown event of input with a listener function. In response, other keys like qwer can be monitored while only those arrows can not.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't those arrows change the focus of the input? If so you'd have to use [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)

Comment: @George sometimes it does  in this case it will cause page to move thats why i want to disable it by prevent its event